# What is the dual problem in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

In linear programming, Von Neumann define the dual of

$$(I)\, \left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
      c^Tx &\to \min\\
Ax &\ge b\\
x&\ge 0
    \end{array}
\right. $$
is the problem
$$(II)\, \left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
      b^Ty &\to \max\\
A^Ty &\le c\\
y&\ge 0
    \end{array}
\right. $$
The question is: How to show that the dual of a dual is the primal?
I know many proof that change ($b^Ty \to \max$) into ($(-b)^Ty \to \min$) and then take the dual. But how can we change like that, because the problem
$$(II')\, \left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
      (-b)^Ty &\to \min\\
A^Ty &\le c\\
y&\ge 0
    \end{array}
\right. $$
is different from (II). What is the relation of (II) and (II') that we can use to change max to min?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it formally. The LP is characterised by the triple $(c,A,b)$. The
dual can then be characterised by $(-b, -A^T, -c)$ (the negative signs to account for $\max \to \min$, and the reversal of direction in the constraint).

You can see that by applying this rule formally twice, we end up with $(c,A,b)$.